# How to convert a BigDecimal to a Double using the query in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am having troubles converting BigDecimal (4 decimal places) to a Double (2 decimal places) in *JasperReports*. I tried CONVERT() and it was erroneous. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: At which point did you use the CONVERT()? (It's SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by conversion.
If you mean typecasting, then simply call BigDecimal.doubleValue()

But I assume you mean the display format - for that you may use the Pattern property of the report field. If you are using iReport then you can select a number format pattern from a number of format presets.

If your needs go beyond that functionality then you can create a custom decimal formatter. Here is what you can do:

1. Create a report variable of type java.text.DecimalFormat
2. Specify new java.text.DecimalFormat(your custom pattern here) as its initial value
3. Call $V{formatter_variable_name}.format(Number) to get a formatted string